# How to dynamically subclass a class and instantate the subclass in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to dynamically subclass a class (say NSString) and instantiate that subclass for testing purposes.  How can I do that in Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you don't need to do what you're seeking to do, but without more specifics it's impossible to know for sure. Because Objective-C is a late-bound language, subclassing for testing purposes is rarely required. Instead, take a look at [class categories](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) or consider a redesign so that you can pass a test double (either stub, fake or mock) via a parameter of type `id` or conforming to a protocol.

For interest, you can use `objc_allocateClassPair(Class superclass, const char *name, size_t extraBytes)` to allocate a new class. You can add methods using `class_addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)` and ivars with `class_addIvar(Class cls, const char *name, size_t size, uint8_t alignment, const char *types)`. Finally, you should register the new class using `objc_registerClassPair(Class cls)`. Find out more in the [Objective-C 2.0 Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). If I find time, I'll test some code and post it here.

Comment: Hi Barry, I am curious how it can be done for educational purposes instead of practical.  Any idea how?

Comment: Yes, I added a roadmap for doing it using the Objective-C 2.0 runtime. If I get time, I'll write/test some code and post it as well.